# Error: Could not find or load main class - Command line

Tags: java, cmd, classpath

I read a hundred posts related to this but nothing seems to help my case.

A strange thing is happening with my commands. To start off, for the current task I need to be using textbook libraries from an algorithms book and the installer from that book also sets up Java SE 7. I have Java 8 JDK installed on my pc from before (if that is info worth knowing). So, for example, when I am running programs which involve methods from that textbook library I write `java-algs4`.

Last night there was something wrong with the Path variables and I wasn't able to compile anything so I was setting some of those and then things started working. However, today, when I tried running `java helloworld` (after doing `javac helloworld.java`) I got the error mentioned in the title. Moreover, I could successfully run another class file in the same directory but after I ran it once, I couldn't anymore and got the error again. This seems like black magic to me!

When I `echo %CLASSPATH%` I get the current directory.

Here are my current java-related PATHs set in my environment variables if this is of any help. The `algs4` is the one from the textbook.

In **User variables - PATH**
*C:\Users\Denitsa\algs4\bin;C:\Users\Denitsa\algs4\java\bin;c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0\bin;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;*

In **System variables - PATH**
_C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Users\Denitsa\algs4\java\bin; C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_31\bin;_

I would really appreciate your help with this, been trying to solve this for a while now!
Thanks.

Comment: Please show the contents of `helloworld.java`. Ideally, show a complete transcript of "here's the source, here's how I compile, here's how I tried to execute, here's the error"...

Comment: The stupidest mistake ever - I wasn't writing the capital letters when running so when I changed that it worked.

Comment: The only mistake made here is the usage of the word "strange". If you just slap yourself on the wrist the next time you want to type it in a problem description and go look for reasonable mistakes instead of mysterious ones, you'll find what is right under your nose a lot faster ;)

Comment: I will have it in mind for next time. This is my very first post here (although I've been spending a lot of time here) and I'm new to the field in general, so I guess I will learn to formulate myself better in time. :) Thanks for the remark!

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to run it without the capital letters in the name. Now it is working.